# Ionic3: Cant install Printer plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm using Ionic3 to do an application to print something. I following the documentaion of Ionic for [Printer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/printer).

After I run

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-printer
```

I run the command:

```
npm install @ionic-native/printer
```

Then I get:

```
npm WARN @ionic-native/printer@5.6.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/printer@5.6.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Someone already had this problem before?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**first install those dependencies**

```
npm install rxjs@6.3.0
npm i @ionic-native/core
```